# Delete session variable with link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm wondering what's the best way to implement a link or a button that deletes a session object ( session[:object] ). I'm storing some data in the browser and users must be able to delete these whenever they want. Any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make a controller (or, alternatively, a non-REST method in your object's existing controller):

Controller

```
class WidgetSessionsController < ApplicationController
  # "Delete" widget session data
  def destroy
    # Remove the widget from the session
    @_current_user = session[:widget] = nil
  end
end
```

routes.rb

```
# obviously you could add create and update here
resources :widget_sessions [only: destroy]
```

View

```
<%= link_to 'Click here to delete your widget session!', widget_session_path(), method: :delete %>
```

Answer (score 3):

I would create a route called `clear_[whatever]`, and bind it to a custom action in your controller.

your route would look like this:

```
get '/clear-[whatever]', to: '[your controller]#clear_[whatever]', via: [:destroy], as: :clear_[whatever]
```

your button would then be:

```
<%= link_to clear_[whatever]_path ... %>
```

and your controller action should do:

```
def clear_[whatever]
  @clear = session[:whatever] = nil
  if @clear ... 
  ...
  else 
  ...
end
```